# Compatibility Problem: Intel Server Chassis SR1500 + Windows Server 2003 R2 + Seagate Barracuda 7200.11 1.5TB

Tags: windows-server-2003, intel, raid1, seagate

I got an Intel Server Chassis SR1500. Since there are 3 slots for hard disk, I put 2 Seagate Barracuda 7200.10 320GB to Slot 0 and 1 to make a RAID1. For the last slot (Slot 2), I put a Seagate Barracuda 7200.11 1.5TB, make it another set of RAID1.

The operating system is Microsoft Windows Server 2003 R2, installed in the 1st RAID1 group. The 1.5TB is used as a share drive for around 100 Windows XP/Vista users.

The 1.5TB corrupted after running for 2 days. In Event Viewer, it said "the file system is corrupted and unusable", reported by ntfs. Files are corrupted and CHKDSK rescued some of the files, in a hidden system folder called found.000.

I am curious, what are the possible causes of the corruption ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Seagate 1.5 TB have a long, sordid history of drive corruption and hardware defects.

**Seagate 1.5TB Drives Randomly Freezing**
http://www.tomshardware.com/news/seagate-barracuda-1.5TB-freezing,6558.html

**Updated: Seagate 1TB Drives Biting The Dust**
http://www.tomshardware.com/news/seagate-7200.11-failing,6844.html

**Seagate customers swamped by Barracuda drive failures**
http://www.theregister.co.uk/2009/01/16/barracuda_failure_plague/

Comment: +1, I don't mean to troll Seagate products, but these drives are infamous.